# Putting an ASP.Net MVC project on a server for team development with VS Pro Team version

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, hosting

Can anyone give me advice on where to start when it comes to setting up a project on a server so that my helper and I can check out code files?  I have a hosting account with Go Daddy - IIS 7, if that can be used.

Also, I'm looking for advice on how to learn more about setting up my database on a server - currently my project has it set up similar to the MVC tutorial "Nerd Dinner".  I have 2 SQL server databases that came with my hosting account package.

Thanks for helping a newbie!

Comment: Do you mean using a public IIS server to host development in progress? I don't recommend that. You should host a server locally for development and publish completed files to the public server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are probably looking to do is setup source control. These days there are two good free options--SVN and Git. Both should work for you, and this isn't the place to have the 399350293456th SVN vs. Git debate. Do some research and pick one.

In any case, you can get hosting for each from a variety of service providers, or setup hosting on your own. At your scale, a provider probably makes sense as it doesn't seem you have the infrastructure to host.

Then each of you can work locally and commit changes to the repository and therefore keep on the proverbial same page.